# failed to 'sadd' a value using key 'b:siren:e' without any errors

Tags: redis

I've tried to execute below commands in redis-cli.
I cannot 'sadd' a value '1' into a set using key 'b:siren:e' exceptively.

```
localhost> sadd b:siren:e 1
1
localhost> smembers b:siren:e

localhost>
```

I've tested on 4.0.0, 4.0.6 and 3.2.11 of redis.

Is there any reasons redis works like this?
What is my mistake?

Comment: Should work and works for me - can't reproduce. The above isn't copy-pasted from the cli though - is it accurate?

Comment: Besides @ItamarHaber's comment, you should also check if some client called `flushdb` or `flushall` after your `sadd` operation.

Comment: @ItamarHaber above is copy-pasted from the cli.  I've just removed ':port' string.  It looks be on my own machine only.

Comment: @for_stack I've tried to 'flushdb', 'flushall' after 'sadd' operation. But the problems's same.

Comment: @Hyeong-JoonKim I assumed so because you had also removed the "(integer)" before the reply from `sadd`